# Jquery Cluetip - using javascript inside tooltip

Tags: jquery, ajax, tooltip, cluetip

I am using [Jquery Cluetip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/) for my tool-tips.
The tool-tip content is loaded with the AJAX function in Cluetip. In the loaded content I want to use Javascript to increase usability.

*index.html:*

```
<img src="edit.png" title="Test" class="popup" rel="ajax-content.html">
```

*onLoad.js:*

```
$('.popup').cluetip({activation: 'click'});
```

*ajax-content.html:*

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Hello world!');
</script>
Test content.
```

The result is a tool-tip appearing on click with the title:'*Test*', content:'*Test content*' and **no** alert saying '*Hello world!*'. FireBug doesn't show the script nor console errors.

Any help on this?

---

*Edit:*

I figured it out.

Cluetip has a default action on processing ajax:

```
ajaxProcess: function(data) {
    data = data.replace(/<(script|style|title)[^<]+<\/(script|style|title)>/gm, '').replace(/<(link|meta)[^>]+>/g,'');
    return data;
}
```

So the fix is:

```
$('.popup').cluetip({
    activation: 'click'.
    ajaxProcess: function(data) {
        return data;
    }
});
```

I'm not sure why Cluetip removes all script/style/title, probably to prevent bugs.

Answer (score 1):

scripts are generally not loaded via jquery's ajax fetching. You typically have to do this yourself via either $.getScript() or by finding script elements and loading the scripts youself.

I assume that cluetip does not do this for you via its rel loading functionality. Also, this is generally not a good idea, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Cluetip offers these options by default. I am doing this to improve usability of my application (E.G. A datepicker on an input field inside the tooltip). Why wouldn't it be a good idea?

Comment: its usually a bad idea to include js files via ajax and run them, ther e is usually a better way to do this. for example: add a class 'datepicker' to all inputs requiring a datepicker. on the callback provided by cluetip 'ajaxprocess', find '.datepicker' in your newly added html and add datepickers to it.